# performSegueWithIdentifier not work in call-back function?

Tags: ios, function, callback, segue

```
 -(void)loginPerform
{
    NSLog(@"start to perform segue!");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"end perform login!");
}
```

The loginPerform function is called in a call-back function.and both two log can print so the performSegueWithIdentifier execute.But the current view doesn't change.

1. view A and view B are connected by Custom Segue.
2. view A embed in Navigation Controller.

BTW: I put a test button to perform segue directly, and it works.
when the loginPerform function is called the next view is always view A when click test button.

I don't understand what happend.anybody can help me?

```
int user_account_delegate(int reqid, char* msg)
{
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: login return %s", msg);
    int reterr = 0;

    if(reqid!=[BLSInstLink getLoginID])
        return -1;

    /* parse the login result (JSON) */
    if(get_json_object_value(msg, KEY_ERROR, VAL_INTEGER, (void*)&reterr)==0)
    {
        if(reterr==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"DEBUG: login succeed.");
            [BLSInstLink setLogined:YES];
            BLSViewController *this = THIS;
            [this loginPerform];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"DEBUG: login failed. err=%d", reterr);
            [BLSInstLink setLogined:NO];
            [BLSInstLink setErrorCode:reterr];
        }
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_LOGINRESULT object:nil];
    return 0;
}
```

This is the callback function which i implement in my own UIViewController.

```
-(void)loginPerform{
    NSLog(@"in loginPerform");//1
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
        NSLog(@"start perform page2");//2
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"end perform page2");//3
    }];
}
```

This is the perform function called in callback function.Just 1 print

```
- (IBAction)test_click:(id)sender {
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SecondPage" sender:self];
}
```

This is a test button to test perform segue. and it works well.

Comment: In what kind of class you are writing this code. UIViewController sublass? Can you elaborate your question by some more code.

Comment: check your segue identifier name. Is it same?

Comment: What thread is the callback called on?

Comment: int user_account_delegate(int reqid, char* msg){
  ....//some code
   [THIS loginPerform];
}
This is the callback function.and i implement it in my own UIViewController.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until your other view controller is done animating, before performing the segue. You can use the new iOS 5 method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"My Segue" sender:self];
}];
```

If you need a pre-iOS 5 way to do it, you should just add a delay to give the animation time before performing the segue.

Otherwise you can go here  [iOS delegate not working with performSegueWithIdentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491410/ios-delegate-not-working-with-performseguewithidentifier)

Answer (score 0):

As it is a custom segue it wont push second view automatically.You need to implement prepareForSegue function in your class similar to this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondPage"])
       {       
          secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
           //add second view as subview of first view.
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thx. i tryed your way,but it seems that there are problems in the view A's dismissViewControllerAnimated. so the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"My Segue" sender:self]; does't run.